# Laravel - conditional filtering with relation table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-7

I have to conditionally filter results in the below query, based on `$search` is present or not.
Below is my query,

```
    Sellers::with(
        'shop:id,width,height,business_id'
    )->with(
        'unit.location:id,name as l_name'
    )->select(
        'sellers.id', 'sellers.name' , 'address'
    )->when($search, function ($query, $search) {
         $query->where('l_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
    })
    ->findOrFail($request->seller_id);
```

The relations are,

Sellers has many units.
Units has one location.

I need to filter the above result for location names based on the availability of search param.
I have tried adding aliases, but they are throwing errors.

How can this be attained?

Comment: you can look into `whereHas` - Querying Relationship Existence

Comment: Tried it. It doesn't seem to work with relations like unit.location.

Comment: it works fine on nested relationships

Comment: What error it throws ? also try this code `function ($query) use ($search)` instead of `function ($query, $search)`

Comment: @lagbox This is what i tried.

Sellers::with(
    'widget:id,width,height,business_id'
            )->whereHas('unit.location', function($q) use($search)
            {
               $q->where('locations.name', $search);
                    
            })
                
                ->select(
                '*'
            )
                
                ->findOrFail($request->seller_id);

Location array is empty in all cases. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @AkhtarMunir No error, the location array is always empty.

Answer (score 1):

The `with` expression in the query builder loads the relations with a second query, ex:

```sql
select * from posts; // returns posts with ids 1, 2, 3
select * from comments where posts_id in (1,2,3);
```

So for your query:
`$query->where('l_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');` is causing a SQL error as the locations table is not joined.

You have two ways to make your query:

### Using a join:

Add a join for your locations table to your query

```php
   ->join('units', ...)
   ->join('locations', ...)
```

### By querying relations:

Replace the when expression in your example by:

```php
    ->when($search, function ($query, $search) {
         $query->whereHas('unit.location', function () {
            $query->where('l_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
         });
    })
```

This will add a `where exists` expression on the locations table that limits the search results. For example:
`` (`select * from posts where exists (select 1 from comments where approved = true and comments.post_id = posts.id )) ``

Comment: I have tried, Sellers::with(
    'widget:id,width,height,business_id')
                
                ->with(
                'unit.location'
            )
                ->when($search, function ($query) use ($search) {
                    $query->whereHas('unit.location', function ($query) use ($search) {
                        $query->where('id', 2);
                    });
            })
                
                ->findOrFail($request->seller_id); The filter in whereHas is still not working. Its always listing all results.

Comment: Could you debug the SQL using `toSql()`>

Also, it would be better to write the queries inside the `Where Exists` with the full name of the table because of the column name collisions. (example `$query->where('locations.id', 2);`

Comment: Also like you mentioned, locations table is joined, the unit.location syntax will join it automatically. All locations are displayed, the issue is when a filter is applied to the location name or id.

Comment: No, the `unit.location` does not use joins and this is what is causing the error. Laravel will make multiple queries to load the relations (each per table). Please recheck the example in the first part of the answer.